# Is the book Stochastic Processes and Calculus from Hassler a good starting point?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, stochastic-calculus

I'm doing a PhD in economics, have done some courses in calculus, linear algebra, statistics and econometrics, so I have some understanding on the subject, but I never used a book to study specifically stochastic processes. I have found this book, Stochastic Processes and Calculus, from Uwe Hassler. It seemed a nice book to start. Just wanted to know if anybody has used it and what they think about it.

Comment: Do you have a particular application in mind?

Comment: Finances and macroeconomics basically. I'm more concerned in understanding the intuition than learning all the proofs, at least initially.